# How to convert Excel logical function concept into R?

Tags: r

I have one excel formula that i am trying to convert in R:`QTL_interval = IF(OR(D3-D2>1000000,C3<>C2),E2+1,E2)`. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f8PE.png)

```
D3 -> Maximum Position 
D2 -> Minimum position
C3 -> Chromosome Number
C2 -> Chromosome Number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble("CHROM" = c("1A", "4A", "5A", "5A", "5A"),
             "POS" = c(560469514, 2846288687, 568234305, 568464107, 568465833))

df %>% 
    mutate(QTL_interval = cumsum(POS - lag(POS) > 1000000 | CHROM != lag(CHROM) | row_number() == 1))
```

The `|` is r's OR operator.  I added a third condition to check if you're at the first row.  Otherwise the first row is `NA` and the cumulative sum doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dewar for your assistance. its running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated the table based on the linked image:

```
df <- data.frame("CHROM" = c("1A", "4A", "5A", "5A", "5A"),
                 "POS" = c(560469514, 2846288687, 568234305, 568464107, 568465833),
                 "QTL interval" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Proposed Solution:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$QTL.interval[i] <- ifelse( (df$POS[i+1] -  df$POS[i] > 1000000) | (df$CHROM[i+1] != df$CHROM[i]), df$QTL.interval[i]+1, df$QTL.interval[i])
}
```

The last row will end up being `NA` since the last iteration will have no table values i+1:

```
  CHROM        POS QTL.interval
1    1A  560469514            1
2    4A 2846288687            1
3    5A  568234305            0
4    5A  568464107            0
5    5A  568465833           NA
```